# Excel speed and size problems

Tags: performance, excel, optimization, size

I am interning at a mutual funds division of a large firm and working on a revenue model. The model is already developed and is huge. I need to optimize it in terms of speed (opening, saving, closing, calculating) and efficiency (better formulas may be?) overall.

Problems are: it is very slow. It has more than 42 worksheets and is 23 MB right now. It links to lot of other excel files on my drive but not to the drives in the networked hard drives.

It uses 'vlookup', 'sumif', and 'sum' a lot. All worksheets are Linked to all others through formulas.

To shed more light, the excel file is basically keeping track of mutual funds (over 50 types) and their number of subcategories. For example, we fetch actual data on funds' performance, funds income, assets under management under each, and more than other 20 such attributes. My excel sheet gets data from these other excel sheets and just reports everything together so that we can make projections of revenue and income over teh next 4-5 years.

To give u scale, total 'sumif' formulas in the workbook are 113000, yes that's correct..more than 100, 000! similarly vlookups are 53000...

I have already switched to manual mode of calculation, removed all macros (they were few, that were just for switching between tabs, and also tried to save as a binary file (binary makes it thrice faster, but I am worried, if the file turns even more large given we are adding stuff to it, would binary be a hindrance to addition of macros or even more vlookups...?)

The major problem comes in opening and saving. Only some vlookups are looking up data gathered by other vlookups. In short my questions would be:

1) How efficient would be the binary file format (have been reading on various forums about this, but still need to 100 percent sure before I recommend that to my department)
2) Can we safely call vlookups as culprit as they are more than 50000
3) is splitting the file, lets say 10 tabs in each, be more efficient than one excel with 42 tabs? is it known to make a difference? assuming I dont change anything else on the formula side, and once I split it, I just reference the new excel sheet here. This is labor intensive as well, as this seems humongous task as well. SO before venturing in this, i need to be sure, if this is the right thought process.

Your help is much appreciated.

Ashu

Comment: Wow.  I suppose migrating off of Excel is not an option.  Excel's a great tool when it's used for what it was designed for, but this really pushes the limits - kind of like using a pick up truck as an open pit mine dump truck.

Comment: are your vlookups using exact match or binary search? generally index/match is faster than vlookup-especially if you lookup the same value to return multiple columns of data

Comment: it is using an exact match, not binary. Index/match, as per my readings on the internet's forums, says it is faster, but not so much. Especially if I need to change 53000 formulas, and other formulas such as sumif (not too many, but still in couple of thousands, depend on these vlookups). What about splitting the file? Am also wondering if the present condition where vlookups are looking in other 'sleeping - not opened' excel files on my hard drive is also a major problem?

Comment: vlookups and similar functions will just eat up your RAM and CPU. If things get this complex I would consider moving to a database solution for at least part of the excel content. It isnt very hard to set up a mySQL database, you could store it on the network and have it approachable by other users as well. Use the Excel as the user interface and work with data connections or VBA/sql statements to interact with the database.

Comment: another approach would be to store all formulas in VBA and have an update button that will have the functions 1) put into the excel 2) calculated through 3) pasted into values batchwise (so for each consecutive step separately...)

Comment: Thanks K_B, Dan, Josie. I ll float these ideas around. Appreciate the help

Comment: If installing new software (e.g. MySQL) would be a problem then you should be able to create a Jet database from within Excel using ADO and query that with SQL

Answer (score 1):

For VLOOKUP try sorting your data and then  using the binary search option of VLOOKUP (its orders of magnitude faster). See [Exact match binary search lookups](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/vlookup-tricks-why-2-vlookups-are-better-than-1-vlookup/)
 If you cannot sort your data consider using a Memory-based lookup [Memlookup](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/speedtools-avlookup2-memlookup-versus-vlookup-performance-power-and-ease-of-use-shootout-part-2-2/)

Comment: Thanks Charles. Sorting is not an option for me, thought on those lines already. I ll try considering the second option

Answer (score 1):

For the speed, i have no answer but for the size problem you can clear all columns and rows after the last cells realy used to reset the last cells ( [Ctrl]+[End] ).
You can also enable the compression of images.

I dev an AddIns with auto install (in french) to include in context menu 3 new buttons:

1. Optimize
2. Optimize **and Save**
3. Toggle Case

[image]

This is based on [KB of Microsoft office 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244435/en) with personals improvement :

1. add compression of images
2. fix bug for Columns
3. feat compatibility with excel 2007 - 2010 - ...

**SOLUTION** > you can download **my *.xla file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxnJeW2acc_INmhlZmY2dldJUFE/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other questions.
XLSB is more efficient than the XLM based formats for opening and saving. The only downside with the binary formats is that its much more diffcult to process the file with external code.
Splitting an Excel file into multiple files will lead to Excel links, which are slow and error prone and generally to be avoided if at all possible.